# Invalid spec selector after upgrading helm template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I've upgraded helm templates (by hand)

Fragment of previous `depoloyment.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2 kind: Deployment metadata:   name: {{ template "measurement-collector.fullname" . }}   labels:
    app: {{ template "measurement-collector.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "measurement-collector.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }} spec:   replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}   selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ template "measurement-collector.name" . }}
      release: {{ .Release.Name }}
```

New one:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "measurement-collector.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "measurement-collector.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "measurement-collector.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "measurement-collector.name" . }}
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
```

new `service.yaml`:

```
  name: {{ include "measurement-collector.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "measurement-collector.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "measurement-collector.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  ports:
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "measurement-collector.name" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
```

Then after running: `helm upgrade -i measurement-collector chart/measurement-collector --namespace prod --wait`

I get:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: Deployment.apps "measurement-collector" is invalid: spec.selector: Invalid value: 
v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{"app.kubernetes.io/name":"measurement-collector", "app.kubernetes.io/instance":"measurement-collector"},         
MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: field is immutable
```

Comment: So the names of the labels have changed. That's tricky if you need to do a straight upgrade of the release - see https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2494 and https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/26202

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you change the selector label, then you will need to purge the release first before deploying:

```bash
kubectl delete deploy <deployment-name>
```

Comment: How do you purge the release?

Comment: @rhand: `kubectl delete deploy <deployment-name>`

Comment: @Here_2_learn @rhand `kubectl delete deploy <deployment-name> --purge` if < helm 3

Comment: This technically works, but its not ideal either. Isn't there a way to achieve this without deleting the deployment?

Answer (score 12):

Though @TigerBear answer is correct, I think I need to explain it in a little bit more details. This problem is caused by a simple reason - immutability of the selectors. You cannot update selectors for (I am not sure this is the complete list, feel free to correct me):

1. ReplicasSets
2. Deployments
3. DaemonSets

In other words, for example if you have a Deployment with label `'my-app: ABC'` within selectors, after that you have updated label inside selector onto this: `'my-app: XYZ'`, and then simply applied this changes, e.g. like this:

```
kubectl apply -f deployment-file-name.yml
```

it will not work - you have to recreate the deployment.

[Related](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/508) github k8s issue, also there is a little note about it in the [Deployment doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#label-selector-updates)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct but I didn't understand them because I was dealing with a helm chart.  In my case, **I changed the helm chart name** and got a similar error.

The change I made in my `helm/Chart.yaml` was

```
apiVersion: v2
name: my-app  ==> was changed to ==> my-new-app
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
```

I didn't realize that that change is used to name other things in the template.  In particular,  the deployment was changed as well.  For example,

```
# Source: my-app/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: my-app       <<< THIS became my-new-app
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: my-app   <<< THIS became my-new-app
```

So the error was actually related to something that I didn't **directly** edit, which is why (to me) the error message was confusing.

By changing the **Chart Name** the **selector** was changed and that is not allowed when running `helm upgrade`.  I also realize the underlying reason `helm upgrade` fails is because kubernetes doesn't support this.